# Cannot use entity classes with NgModule Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in a project with Angular 2 + Typescript and I have develop the app bootstraping with NgModule recently.

I am using some ES5 classes to represent Entities in services and components, but these are not recognized by external libraries such as zone.js or platform-browser.

Console is logging this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

How can I export these classes in Ngmodule so that can be accessed from external sources?

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       RouterModule,
       FormsModule,
       HttpModule,
       JsonpModule,
       routing
   ],
   providers: [
       HeroService,
       appRoutingProviders
   ],
   declarations: [
       HeroComponent
   ],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Let's say I am using a Hero class like this:

```
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I try to use this Hero class in Services and Promises I am getting always the error because is not provided in NgModule definition.

Comment: Please provide code that demonstrates what you tried.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer something like that

Comment: `routing` doesn't seem to be a module. You can list them in the `exports: [...]` parameter of `@NgModule()`. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: routing is the result of export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes); @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Sorry you are right, forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that changes in rc5 are not allowing to mangle your minified Javascript file:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618

Solution was to stop mangling, until there is a fix for this issue.